# WebDriver SSL Certificate accepting not working on sub domain

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, ssl-certificate

I'm automating a Https login flow using FirefoxDriver(profile) in Java.

I get two SSL certificate warnings, one which: `profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true)` takes care of but for some reason the second SSL cert still shows and stops my script from running.

The only think I can think of is the second SLL cert shows on a different sub-domian (idapi.) where as the previous SLL cert was on id. But then I've checked the properties of the cert and the signature is the same.

How can I get past this issue?

I've tried `setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true)` but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was the selenium version in my pom.xml file. For some reason 2.32.0 was not working (maybe a bug) but changing to 2.35.0 and the following code worked fine:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 3):

did you try this way?

```
final DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```